# How Can I Test Image-Requiring Styled Components in Mocha?

Tags: mocha.js, styled-components

I have a Styled Component that uses a `require`-d image file:

```
<MenuIcon src={require("../styles/menu-icon.png")}/>
```

Doing this (ie. passing a `require`-ed image file) is a standard pattern in Styled Components ... but obviously it makes for invalid JS.

As a result, when I try to test that component, I get:

> /home/me/project/src/styles/menu-icon.png:1 SyntaxError: Invalid or

> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Jest apparently has a module name mapper that let's it solve this ... but I'm using Mocha, and as far as I can tell Mocha has no such resource.

So, my question is: in Mocha (without `moduleNameMapper`) how can I test a component that imports (`require`s) an image?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in an issue thread for Ava (another test runner): https://issuehunt.io/r/avajs/ava/issues/2525

Basically you need to make a `test-compiler.js` file which tells `require` to just return `null` for non-JS extensions:

```
/**
 * Disable webpack-specific features for tests, since tests do not use webpack 
 * to handle these
 * @see https://issuehunt.io/r/avajs/ava/issues/2525
*/
require.extensions['.css'] = function () {
  return null;
};
require.extensions['.png'] = function () {
  return null;
};
require.extensions['.jpg'] = function () {
 return null;
};
```

Then you just need to tell Mocha to require that file.  You can use an argument when you run Mocha (`-r test-compiler.js`), or you can make a .mocharc.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  exit: true,
  require: ['jsdom-global/register', '@babel/register', './test-compiler.js' ],
  spec: '!(node_modules)/**/*.spec.{js,cjs,mjs}',
```

};

The important part being this line:

```
require: ['jsdom-global/register', '@babel/register', './test-compiler.js' ],
```

which brings in other requirements (Babel and JS DOM) first, and then requires our `test-compiler.js`.